# difference between .'@value' and .@value in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have seen a property being accessed in difference ways as .'@value' and .@value. What is the difference?

what exactly quotation do in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where have you seen `o.'@value'`?

Calling `o.@value` will ignore the getter in the object and get you the `value` property directly.

So calling `o.'@value'` will get a property called `@value` (which in Groovy isn't a valid property name for a class)

#### Edit from example

Ahhh, right that's a badly explained example imho.  When slurping xml, the `@attr` form is a special form will access an attribute of the node.

Now groovy lets you do the following:

```
def a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

// Will call getBytes() on every string in the list
assert a*.bytes == [[97], [98], [99]]

// So will this!
assert a.bytes == [[97], [98], [99]]
```

As you can see in the second `assert`, we don't have the spread-dot operator `*.` but it still works and calls `getBytes` on every element in the list.

With [the xml example](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser) you link to, it's doing:

```
records.car.findAll{ it.country.text() =~ '.*s.*a.*' }.'@make'
```

So it's calling the 'make' attribute on each item in the list.  If it were without quotes:

```
records.car.findAll{ it.country.text() =~ '.*s.*a.*' }.@make
```

It would try to get the `make` property of an ArrayList (which obviously doesn't exist).

I would say a less confusing way of writing it would be:

```
records.car.findAll{ it.country.text() =~ '.*s.*a.*' }*.@make
```

As that makes it more obvious what is going on...

Comment: Could you please take a look at this http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser. it refers to the props like this firstRecord.'@make'

Comment: @iCode Updated my answer...hope it makes sense ;-)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. So .'@XX' is equivalent of *.@XX ?! That seems odd. I mean accodingly yo your intial command, calling o.'@XX' will get a property called @XX though but that is not the case in here?! Which one is correct then?

Comment: The `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser` return `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` and `groovy.util.Node` respectively.  Calling `@attr` on these classes gets the `attribute` of the xml node.  Calling `@attr` on a regular object bypasses the getter and returns the property value. It's different when using XmlSlurped or XmlParsed results